# Migrating Oracle specific sql to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Oracle:

```
select RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE ORDER BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE, ROWNUM)  from CAR_SEARCH_GTT;
```

Postgres: ?

Issue: there is no Rownum in postgresql, if we use `row_number() over ()` instead of `ROWNUM`, the PSQLException would be thrown.

```
ERROR: window functions are not allowed in window definitions
```

Question: How to convert the query above to PostgreSQL?

Comment: What is the `order by` on the overall `select`?  The reason I ask is because Oracle generates `rownum` based on the `order`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for responding me, I've updated the query. sorry that's my fault.

Comment: @MikeOrganek yes, but Postgresql didn't support ROWNUM

Comment: Using the same column in `partition by` and `order by` still makes no sense.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. The query does not make a lot of sense. It seems your partitioning is done in an nondeterministic way. And will most likely behave differently when ported.

Comment: @HB: Mike's question was intended to find out what the intended sort order is. If there is an `order by` in the overall query, it's highly likely that you can simply move those columns into the window function: `partition by equip_unit_init_code order by <columns from the global order by>)`

Comment: What determines the `ROWNUM` in your query?  Does it come from a subquery?  Is it the default from how Oracle read the row?

Comment: The query above was used on the project, means it was working properly. now I have to migrate it to postgresql

Comment: @MikeOrganek https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion#ROWNUM_and_ROWID

Comment: Was the `ROWNUM` generated according to an explicit `ORDER BY` in a subquery?

Comment: If you want to migrate it, you need to understand and explain what it does - especially if it uses things that don't really make sense and might indicate a deeper problem with the query itself (I wouldn't be surprised if this only "happens" to work properly in Oracle and might break completely if some  external things change. The sort order used,  isn't really deterministic). Showing us only part of the query doesn't help in this case, we need to see the complete query.

Answer (score 2):

Using a non-deterministic `ROWNUM` makes sense if you do not want `RANK()` numbers repeated in the case of ties.

That said, as @a_horse_with_no_name said, it make no sense whatsoever to `ORDER BY` the same column that you `PARTITION BY`.

Please try this:

```
with numbered as (
  select *, row_number() over () as rnum
    from CAR_SEARCH_GTT
)
select RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE 
                         ORDER BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE, rnum)  
  from CAR_SEARCH_GTT;
```

If there is a PK on `CAR_SEARCH_GTT` as `id`, then you can do something like this:

```
select RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE 
                         ORDER BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE, id)  
  from CAR_SEARCH_GTT;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  Without an explicit sort, the rows are in arbitrary order.  If the sort keys are not unique, then ties are in an arbitrary order.

Then, you don't need to repeat the `PARTITION BY` key in the `ORDER BY` for window functions.  You could write what you want in Oracle as:

```
select RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE ORDER BY ROWNUM) 
from CAR_SEARCH_GTT;
```

Despite the `rownum`, the ordering is *arbitrary*.  Oracle makes no guarantee on the ordering within each group.

The one effect of `rownum` is to have a different value on each row.  Hence, there are no ties.  This is more clearly expressed using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE ORDER BY ROWNUM) 
from CAR_SEARCH_GTT;
```

Oracle requires an `ORDER BY` clause, so anything can go there.

In Postgres, you can do the same thing by removing the `ORDER BY` -- Postgres extends the syntax of `ROW_NUMBER`.  So the equivalent is:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EQUIP_UNIT_INIT_CODE) 
from CAR_SEARCH_GTT;
```

In both cases, you might have an appropriate key for ordering -- perhaps an identity column or creation date.